# How to concat the row output of iterrows to another pandas DataFrame with the same columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have the following two pandas DataFrames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3],
                    "B": ["a", "b", "c"],
                    "C": [7, 43, 15]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [4, 5],
                    "B": ["c", "d"],
                    "C": [12, 19]})
```

Now, I want to iterate over the rows in `df1`, and if a certain condition is met for that row, add the row to `df2`.

For example:

```
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row["C"] == 43:
        df2 = pd.concat([row, df2])

df2.head()
```

Should give me output:

```
A    B    C
4    c    12
5    d    19
2    b    43
```

But instead I get an output where the column names of the DataFrames appear in the rows:

```
    0   A   B   C
A   2   NaN     NaN     NaN
B   b   NaN     NaN     NaN
C   43  NaN     NaN     NaN
0   NaN     4.0     c   12.0
1   NaN     5.0     d   19.0
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with boolean indexing on `df1`.

```
pd.concat([df2, df1[df1['C'] == 43]], ignore_index=True)
```

The `df1[df1['C']==43]]` part takes a slice of df1 based on the condition the column C being equal to 43 and concats it to df2.

Output:

```
    A   B   C
0   4   c   12
1   5   d   19
2   2   b   43
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.merge()`

- `pd.merge()` take list of two dfs and merge them horizontally if no axis is defined.
- In your case pass `df2` along with `df1[df1["C"] == 43]` which will return only those rows who have 43 in its column C.
- `reset_index()` so that output don't have duplicate index values.

```
df2 = pd.concat([df2,df1[df1["C"] == 43]]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df2)

        A   B   C
    0   4   c   12
    1   5   d   19
    2   2   b   43
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this

```
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row["C"] == 43:
        df2.loc[len(df2.index)] = row

df2.head()
```